# Deriving a pendulum Mass equation swinging in a horizontal wind speed

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I saw this question on chegg.com while I was looking for ways to model a pendulum swinging in constant wind speed.

This is the equation that was provided, where c is the coefficient drag, V is the wind speed

$$
mL \ddot{\theta} + cL\dot{\theta} + mgsin\theta - c V cos\theta = 0
$$

I was wondering how did the term "$ cVcos\theta $" came about?
Or is this term conveniently placed there for the sake of the question? If not how can start the derivation process that includes this term?

This is the [link](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/-simple-pendulum-mass-m-length-l-swinging-horizontal-wind-speed-v-satisfies-equation-ml-cl-q45367853) to the webpage. I don't have an account there and also do not require the solutions for the question found in the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$cV\cos\theta$ is the torque per unit length on the pendulum due to the horizonal wind. The actual torque would be $cVL\cos\theta$, but an $L$ term has already been cancelled from each term in the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(mg\sin{\theta})$ represents a constant vertical force, $(-cV\cos{\theta})$ must be a constant horizontal force. Since the magnitude portion is $cV$, it is clearly the drag force component along $\theta$

The two forces balance at:

$$ \theta_0 = \arctan{\frac{cV}{mg}}$$

which is an equilibrium position. You can define

$$\phi=\theta-\theta_0$$

and the equation of motion for $\phi$ becomes:

$$mL\ddot\phi+cL\dot\phi+\sqrt{(mg)^2+(cV)^2}\sin\phi =0$$